# Creating Observable that batches like ring buffer (advice needed)

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java, disruptor-pattern

After finding no proper solution for my problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33609107/observable-to-batch-like-lmax-disruptor), I've decided to implement this.

However I lack experience of working with monads and things like lift(..) still look a bit magical to me...

**The purpose of me opening this is so that those who had implemented some custom stuff on top of rxjava, could give me advice on how to implement this.**

Now what is this all about, here is the interface.

[image]

I suppose this will be self explanatory for most of you, but to be sure i'll bring an example.

Imagine we have a subscriber (consumer) which actually does persistance to database, well obviously if you give it 1 or 1000 objects to persist the difference wont be factor of 1000 it will be factor of 10 or much less, which means it is a consumer that can adopt to load... So it is stupid to push one item at a time while you can persist many at a time, on the other side its stupid to wait to some batch of N elements to fill up till you persist (one second you might get 1000 elements on other you might get none, so suppose we dont know how frequent incoming data is)...

So what we have now is `Observable.batch()` which will ask for some N size of the batch and we will often wait without working... On the other side we have `Disruptor` which does exactly what we want but does not provide beautiful interface of `Observable`... `Disruptor` will process a single element and while you process it it will collect all the incoming elements and next time you'll get batch of everything that was collected since your consumer was busy with the last value...

Currently I suppose that I shall use `Observable.from()` to implement this or `lift()`...

**Please share your thoughts on this, maybe there are already solutions available for this that I'm unaware of, or I'm about to implement this in a wrong way...**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an operator that will batch values that piled up behind an asynchronous boundary:

```
public final class OperatorRequestBatcher<T> 
implements Operator<List<T>, T> {
    final Scheduler scheduler;
    public OperatorRequestBatcher(Scheduler scheduler) {
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
    }
    @Override
    public Subscriber<? super T> call(Subscriber<? super List<T>> t) {
        Scheduler.Worker w = scheduler.createWorker();
        RequestBatcherSubscriber<T> parent = 
                new RequestBatcherSubscriber<>(t, w);

        t.add(w);
        t.add(parent);

        return parent;
    }

    static final class RequestBatcherSubscriber<T> 
    extends Subscriber<T> implements Action0 {
        final Subscriber<? super List<T>> actual;
        final Scheduler.Worker w;
        final Queue<T> queue;
        final AtomicInteger wip;

        volatile boolean done;
        Throwable error;

        public RequestBatcherSubscriber(
                Subscriber<? super List<T>> actual, 
                Scheduler.Worker w) {
            this.actual = actual;
            this.w = w;
            this.wip = new AtomicInteger();
            this.queue = new SpscLinkedArrayQueue<>(256);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(T t) {
            if (done) {
                return;
            }
            queue.offer(t);
            schedule();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            if (done) {
                return;
            }
            error = e;
            done = true;
            schedule();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            done = true;
            schedule();
        }

        void schedule() {
            if (wip.getAndIncrement() == 0) {
                w.schedule(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void call() {
            int missed = 1;

            final Queue<T> q = queue;
            final Subscriber<? super List<T>> a = actual;
            final AtomicInteger wip = this.wip;

            for (;;) {

                List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();

                for (;;) {
                    boolean d = done;
                    T v = q.poll();
                    boolean e = v == null;

                    if (isUnsubscribed()) {
                        q.clear();
                        return;
                    }

                    if (d) {
                        Throwable err = error;
                        if (err != null) {
                            a.onError(err);
                            return;
                        } else
                        if (e) {
                            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                                a.onNext(list);
                            }
                            a.onCompleted();
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    if (e) {
                        break;
                    }

                    list.add(v);
                }

                if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                    a.onNext(list);
                }

                missed = wip.addAndGet(-missed);
                if (missed == 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PublishSubject<Integer> ps = PublishSubject.create();
        TestScheduler sch = Schedulers.test();

        ps.lift(new OperatorRequestBatcher<>(sch))
        .subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace, 
                () -> System.out.println("Done"));

        ps.onNext(1);
        ps.onNext(2);

        sch.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        ps.onNext(3);

        sch.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        ps.onNext(4);
        ps.onNext(5);
        ps.onNext(6);
        ps.onCompleted();

        sch.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

Note, however, what you described in the API is a form of a hot Observable: cold sources don't coordinate across multiple Subscribers. For that you need to create a custom `ConnectableObservable`.

`publish()` may work for `disruptForEachSubscriber` but `publish().observeOn()` for `disruptForAllSubscriber` is not likely because `observeOn` will request a bunch of values and `publish` would interpret it as a successfull processing of N batches.

Comment: yes hot observables are exactly what i need :) btw are cold observables used often?

Comment: Cold observables are the dominant kind and we usually suggest trying solutions with cold observables before attempting a hot one.

Comment: dont you think it would be smarter to have a AtomicReference<List> as a data structure, and when the value is to be added add to current list under that reference, and when it shall be emitted a new list is put under the reference and the previous one will be emitted..

Comment: Such operation requires atomicity which you won't get with AtomicReference because list.add() may run concurrenlty with list.iterator() on the other side. So either you need to synchronize around list add and list replacement or do copy-on-write.

Comment: Could you please explain why are you redefining final fields? http://imgur.com/vLdcDhz i've seen such approach many times but those were not final...

Comment: When atomic operations happen, the JVM is forced to re-read even constant fields and is an unnecessary penalty. By defining them local (final), there is a much higher likelihood they stay in registers and thus reducing overhead. Adding final modifier is matter of taste and a clear intention for read-only use.

Comment: thanks i didnt know that. I'm trying to test the class you've provided but it seem not to work for me... please look at this http://pastie.org/10578164, last output shall be 10000 but i'm getting this http://imgur.com/25lqUcX is there somethign i'm doing wrong? (i'm getting different results every time)

Comment: I get `RxNewThreadScheduler-1 : 10000` all the time. Looped your code 100 times, moved it to another scheduler and everything was still fine.

Comment: Only modification i've made to your code is replacing SpscLinkedArrayQueue with ArrayBlockingQueue but i cant understand how that could enable this behaviour...

Comment: ArrayBlockingQueue has a capacity bound so onNext will drop values whereas SpscLinkedArrayQueue will grow as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer (akarnokd has already given an awesome one), just a longer comment.

This is an operator I also find very useful. I use it whenever I've got a hot source and a slow subscriber - I use some aggregation strategy to aggregate the events that have piled up during the consumption, and consume the aggregated result.

Examples:

- A reactive plotting library. User moves the mouse, drags the plots, but the rendering is slow, so I aggregate the user's actions before rendering a new version
- Plotting again, this time displaying data lazily acquired from the server over TCP/IP. As the user reveals new parts of a long plot, requests for new data for the server are being generated. Before sending out a new TCP request packet, I aggregate all the requests into one.
- [ObserveLatestOn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967263/how-to-implement-observelateston-in-rxjava-rxscala) is a more specific version of this problem, where the "aggregation" is simply taking the last element.

In the C# world, this operator is called [BufferIntrospective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880247/buffer-while-processing-items). I've managed to write my own version using [zxswing's help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967263/how-to-implement-observelateston-in-rxjava-rxscala), but I'll definitely have a look into this code once I have time.

One thing that is slightly different in my implementation is that my variant has one more parameter, `sendFinalBufferedItemsBeforeCompletion: Boolean`, that specifies how should the unsubscription behavior look like. When `true`, it sends the last batch of items that have accumulated before `OnComplete`, when `false`, it `OnComplete`s immediately. For my use cases both usages make sense.